Jumpy keyboard when trie to add constraints in custom keyboard
I was trying to build my own keyboard to use across all iOS apps. When i tried to add height constraint to it, the keyboard height keeps increasing
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
  
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 260)
    ])
  }
}

Here is a gif
https://s11.gifyu.com/images/SBHgS.gif
